# How to increase the connection timeout to a remote ipython notebook server?

Tags: client-server, jupyter-notebook, connection-timeout

I use ipython notebook on the browser of my laptop that connects to a remote ipython notebook server in my office. The problem is that if the network is down for a *very short* period, the connection will be closed. Then to reconnect to the server,  I "just" need to refresh the browser, but which is actually quite annoying if the size of the notebook is large.

The question is can I increase the connection timeout (just like such options for ssh-server), so that the connection is not lost at all even if the network is down for a short time.

Comment: If your server has Linux operating system then you can use tmux session. It will make sure that even if your connection gets lost, your process will still keep on running in the backgound.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your `jupyter_notebook_config.py` and check the following variables in the file.

`cull_idle_timeout
shutdown_no_activity_timeout`

You can checkout the documentation for these variables [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html?highlight=shutdown_no_activity_timeout)

They shouldn't be enabled by default, but since you are connected to an external server your connection is likely dropped until its refreshed. There might be security reasons for this. Might be a good idea to speak to your Sys. Admin as well before you enable them :)